# Android enviando POST Json usando JAX-RS recebendo objeto com array null

Tags: java, json, rest, post, jax-rs

Estou tentando postar um objeto mas o array só vem null.. alguém pode me dizer o que está errado?

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Produto implements Serializable{

    private String nome;
    get e set...

    private List<Tipo> tipos;
    get e set...

}

@XmlRootElement
public class Tipo implements Serializable{

    private String nome;
    get e set...

}
```

este é o metodo com suas anotações

```
@POST
@Path("/cadastrar")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addProduto(Produto produto)
```

segue o formato do json que estou enviando

```
{
"nome":"Teste produto",
"tipos":[{"nome":"Teste 1"},{"nome":"Teste 2"},{"nome":"Teste 3"}]
}
```

o problema é que chega o produto somente com o nome, o List está vindo null, alguem tem ideia do que seja?!

Comment: Primeira coisa: teste o WS usando um cliente qualquer para se certificar de que o JSON retornado está realmente igual a esse. Se não tiver nenhum, há uma extensão para o Chrome chamada Postman que faz bem o trabalho. Segundo, se estiver tudo certo no servidor, poste o código que chama o WS e recebe o objeto vazio.